# How can i use annotation to load values for a field in java

Tags: java, annotations

I have a map they key of the map is an enum and has some values.

I have a java class with fields, the fields are annotated with the enum values, now i want to set the values from the map to the fields, any suggestions,idea how to go about it?

I am using plain old reflection, but is there a better way to achieve this , something in spring or some thing from apache commons etc?

e.g

```
Map<Myenum,String> map = new HashMap<Myenum,String();
map.add(Myenum.Value1, "1");
map.add(Myenum.Value2, "2");
map.add(Myenum.Value3,"3");
```

i have a java class like

```
MyClass{

 @Use(fieldName=Myenum.Value1)
 String Field1;

 @Use(fieldName=Myenum.Value2)
 String Field2;
@Use(fieldName=Myenum.Value3)
 Object Field3;
@Use(fieldName=Myenum.Value4)
 Integer Field4;
}
```

what i want to MyClass class to be created and fields(Field1,Field2,Field3, Field4 ) to loaded with values from the map with keys matching the annotation on the fields.

e.g field1 should have vaule 1 becuase the annotation of field1 matches the key for the entry 1 in the map.

May be something similar to how Jaxws @XMLElement annotated fields gets the value loaded from an xml/soap

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Spring has a custom interceptor/handler for custom annotations. You can do this pretty easily with basic reflection.

1. Create your `Map`.
2. Get the `Class` object for your class.
3. Get the declared `Field`s for that class.
4. Check if each `Field` has the annotation `Use`. If it does, get its `fieldName` attribute and retrieve the corresponding element from the `Map`.
5. Create an instance of your class with some version of `newInstance()`.
6. Set each found `Field` on that instance with the element you got from the `Map`.
7. Handle type conversion, invalid types or fields that don't have a corresponding element.

Comment: Thanks sotirios, thats what i am doing presently, was just thinking if there is some better way of doing it.